# Low-dimensional binary classification datasets

Tags: neural-network, dataset, data, synthetic-feature

If one would like to study aspects of neural networks (say, in an academic paper), and would like to experiment on binary classification of vectors in low-dimensional space (say dim=2 or dim<6); what are standard/good datasets for that? Probably synthetic, but possibly also not. So, I am thinking of datasets which are ``generic" enough to be considered representative for an academic study of neural net behavior.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a *generic enough dataset*. If you are planning for an academic study, I would suggest to use multiple different datasets that cover a huge variety of characteristics. Most good data science studies do so.

If you are looking for real world datasets then it would be best to search repositories like [kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets), [openML](https://www.openml.org/search) or [UCI](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets.php) for datasets that suit your case.

**Note:** Depending on the subject of the study, one should be careful to generalize from low-dimensional datasets to general aspects of neural networks. But without knowing more about the study, I can not say whether this would be a point.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I meant, say, a series of datasets which will be kind-of representative in some sense, so that an exposed phenomenon on it will be presumed as a "real" phenomenon which probably happens generically enough. I also thought about your point about low-dim vs. high-dim... It is just that what I check is quite computation-heavy so for now I thought checking lower-dim stuff. But I will have this in mind, thanks.